# pdf2swf error while upload document file in openmeetings

Tags: pdf2swf, openmeetings

openmeetings-2.1.1 in my system,i have install ghostscript,ImageMagick-6.8.9 and swftools, when i try to upload document file like .ppt,.doc file, it upload successfully but when i drag to white board it give me error like below.

```
key: processSWF
process: generateSwf
command; [pdf2swf, -s, insertstop, -s, poly2bitmap, -i, -j, 85, -s, zoom=72,    
/home/PROJECTNAME/web/PROJECTNAME/FOLDER/apache-
openmeetings/webapps/openmeetings/upload/files/
be44f8c982e2ca52610b691c3dbda38e/be44f8c982e2c
a52610b691c3dbda38e.pdf,
/home/PROJECTNAME/web/FOLDER/public_html/apache-
openmeetings/webapps/openmeetings/upload/files/
be44f8c982e2ca52610b691c3dbda38e/be44f8c982e2
ca52610b691c3dbda38e.swf]
exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pdf2swf": error=2, No such file or   
directory
error: Cannot run program "pdf2swf": error=2, No such file or directory
exitValue: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pdf2swf": error=2, No such file or 
directory
```

i got this error in dialog box.i have Google a lot, kindly help me to figure out this problem.

thank you.

Comment: Do you have `pdf2swf` in your path?

Answer (score 1):

You Have to edit the "swftools_path" in configuration!

If you don't have swftools you should install version 2012-10-15-1307, the newest version doesn't work!